# Adding Specific Coordinates of a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, operation

I am trying to find the sum of certain coordinates in a matrix.

I have a `N x M` matrix. I have a vector which contains `2xM` values. Every pair of values in the vector is a coordinate in the matrix. Hence their are `M` number of coordinates. I want to find the sum of all of the coordinates without using a for loop.

Is there a matrix operation I can use to get this?

Thanks

Comment: sum of the coordinates? or sum of the values at these coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it the vector contains the (row,column) coordinates to the matrix elements. You can just transform them into matrix element number indices. This example shows how to do it. I'm assuming that your coordinate vector looks like this: 
[n-coordinate1 m-coordinate1 n-coordinate2 m-coordinate2 ...]

```
n = 5; % number of rows
m = 5; % number of columns
matrix = round(10*rand(n,m)); % An n by m example matrix
% A vector with 2*m elements. Element 1 is the n coordinate, 
% Element 2 the m coordinate, and so on. Indexes into the matrix:
vector = ceil(rand(1,2*m)*5); 
% turn the (n,m) coordinates into the element number index:
matrixIndices = vector(1:2:end) + (vector(2:2:end)-1)*n); 
sumOfMatrixElements = sum(matrix(matrixIndices)); % sums the values of the indexed matrix elements
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the centroid of your `2xM` array `coords`, then you can simply write

```
centroid = mean(coords,2)
```

If you want to find the weighted centroid, where each coordinate pair is weighted by the corresponding entry in the `MxN` array `A`, you can use `sub2ind` like this:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A),coords(1,:)',coords(2,:)');

weights = A(idx);

weightedCentroid = sum( bsxfun( @times, coords', weights), 1 ) / sum(weights);
```

If all you want is the sum of all the entries to which the coordinates point, you can do the above and simply sum the weights:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A),coords(1,:)',coords(2,:)');

weights = A(idx);

sumOfValues = sum(weights);
```

Comment: Oh yes the sub2ind function. It's prettier than my vector(1:2:end) + (vector(2:2:end)-1)*n) -> upvote. But I understood that the indices are in a vector, not a matrix.

Comment: @solimanelefant: I assume `2xM` means `2-by-M`, so indices would be in each column of the array. I agree, though, the question is not super clear on that.